Slightly older lady and a young student hook up
There is this one movie I am sure is foreign (European). It's 1980s or 1990s or early 2000s. I saw it like 2 to 3 months ago. Mostly 80s or 90s.
In this movie the lady is a little unstable. Her husband is part of a rebellion and so he is in jail or in court. She is alone, so this young student who first sees her on a building top develops an affair with her which is quite intense.
The young guy's father is a psychiatrist or some doctor and he treats this lady by doing therapy. She comes on to him sometimes as well.
The lady sort of moves into a new house and so the mother in law or owner of the house tie threads around the house to stop people from going. They have a piano in the new house. The lady and young guy have intense sex.

any idea from what year it was? When did you see it last?

its 1980s or 1990s or early 2000s..i saw it like 2 to 3 months before....its mostly 80s or 90s...sorry dont know exact year....they will have a piano in the new house....

The Italian Devil in the Flesh from 1986, based on a novel from 1923.

An Italian high school student named Andrea becomes infatuated with Giulia, an older woman he sees outside his classroom window. Giulia's fiancé, a leftist radical, has been jailed and is currently on trial for political crimes. Andrea and Giulia meet, and begin rendezvousing at her apartment, where a sexual relationship quickly unfolds. The situation is complicated when the fiancé's mother realizes this, and confronts Andrea's father. Andrea's father is a psychiatrist who treats patients with psychoanalysis. He has treated Giulia in the past. The psychiatrist finds himself a victim of Giulia's sexual advances, which he attributes to madness.

The roped-off rooms and the piano are in there as well. (I'd include clips, but they're pretty risque, so here's the poster instead.)

